# I own a garage with 8 bicycle racks, why can I only fill 3 slots?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I bought the Eclyps Towers apt. 31, which has 10- vehicle slots that'd never given me any problems, the garage also contains a bicycle rack with 8 slots on the wall, but I can only fill 3 of them. Is there a feat (or something else) I have to complete before I can fill all 8 slots?
The slots are filled as followed:
BMX
(empty)
BMX 
(empty) 
(empty) 
TRYCYCLE RACING BIKE
(empty) 
(empty)

Answer (score 1):

Just because there are 8 bicycle slots doesn't mean there can be 8 stored in them. Rockstar puts lots of things in apartments that can't be used. Like the hallways. Buy another apartment when the new DLC comes out.

Answer (score -1):

Its a glitch, I got it too once. You are only supposed to use three bikes, so good luck finding what to do with the empty spaces.

Comment: Do you have any proof that this is a glitch?

Comment: Thx 4 help. I dont know its an actual glitch or just a temp bug, but I destroyed my bmx and replaced it, stole another bmx getting back to garage and stored it, a few moments later I got the text that my bmx arrived so now I have 4 bikes. the 4th bike isnt interactible but I thought it was interesting.

Answer (score -2):

The extra spots are part of the graphics.In most bikeracks I've seen in my state,the bike riders space out their bikes.

Comment: To clarify, your basing your answer off real life? He is talking about a video game. Just because that's how it is in real life, does not mean that's how its going to be in a game.